# How bad is it to eat a mostly keto diet, but still eat carbs and sugars?

Tags: ketosis

My spouse is about to start a keto diet. Functionally this means that most, but not all, of the meals I eat will be keto.

If I don't fully commit to the diet (i.e. I don't cut out carbs and sugars), are there any adverse effects?

I'm fine with my current weight (or rather, weight loss isn't a goal). My concern is that eating a mostly keto diet but never getting into ketosis could cause an increase in weight or other health issues.

Comment: I’m closing this question because questions about diet and nutrition are off topic unless directly connected to medical treatment.